# changing the source between different properties (Big Query - Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

i have 2 properties in google analytics (x - y). I wanted to know the "source" of "y" but if the user entered "x" and then clicked "y" (same session), I would have to replace the "source" of "y" with the "source" of " x ". Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to string together the session across two different properties in BQ, you need to have data that "connects" the two sessions in the x and y properties together. Without this data, you won't be able to do this.

Another solution would be to setup cross-domain tracking and just track the traffic for both domains in the same GA property.